# Redirecting output to a variable?

Tags: command-line, bash, redirect

I'm interesting in directing the output from two commands to a variable.  I don't want the output to be displayed on the screen, but instead assigned to a variable within my script so that I can use it again.

what I am doing is getting the file size from a directory using the commands seen below:

```
ls -l /var/spool | wc -c
```

This command gets me the file size in bytes and displays the output as an integer.  I am interested in getting this integer assigned to a variable of my liking so that I can compare it against another variable later

This doesn't seem to work:

```
size = ls -l /var/spool | wc -c
```

Would redirection work?

Like this....

```
ls -l /var/spool | wc -c > size
```

Either way I want this numeric output to be assigned to a variable and not displayed on the screen.

Any suggestions are very welcomed!

Comment: This will not give you file size but count the characters of the `ls` list output.

Answer (score 12):

It seems quite straightforward.

```
romano@RRyS:~$ size=$(ls -l /var/spool | wc -c)
romano@RRyS:~$ echo $size
476
```

The shell syntax `$(command)` executes `command`, and returns the standard output: just save it in a variable.

Your command:

```
ls -l /var/spool | wc -c > size
```

will create a file named  `size` in the current directory (containing the number and a newline).

Comment: or back-quote the command: `size=\`ls -l /var/spool | wc -c\``. use this format in your answer: "`` size=\`ls -l /var/spool | wc -c\` ``" without double quotes ;)

Comment: @KasiyA I prefer to use `$()` for the reasons explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9449788/2907484 :-)

Comment: (1) After doing `ls -l /var/spool | wc -c > size_file`, you could `read size_var < size_file`. (2) See also [Can $() always replace backticks for command substitution?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26929556/3960947)

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the solution offered by [Rmano's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/551953/147044), but if you want to use only redirection:

```
read size < <(ls -l /var/spool | wc -c)
```

Comment: The main benefit of using only redirection is that it doesn't swallow errors (depending on how you have your script set up for pipe processing - `set -e`, `set -o pipefail`, etc.). So if you use `$(…)` your script will always continue, whereas with redirection it can be set up to fail. (which may be what you want, or not).

Comment: idk I'm getting `syntax error near unexpected token '<'`